# How to prove this identity for discrete random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

How to prove that $E(ξE(η|G)) = E(ηE(ξ|G))$, where $ξ$, $G$ and $η$ are random discrete variables. Of course, if both parts exist.

Comment: By linearity of expectation, you can change it to $E(\xi)E(\eta\mid G) = E(\eta)E(\xi\mid G)$. I suspect that that's easier to work with. That being said, what is $G$? I can't imagine that this is true if, for instance, $G$ is $\eta=0$.

Comment: @Arthur, G is random discrete variable too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer $G$ must be looked at as a $\sigma$-algebra (eventually generated by a random variable).

Characteristic for $\mathbb E[\xi\mid G]$ is that it satisfies:$$\int_A\xi(\omega)P(d\omega)=\int_A\mathbb E[\xi\mid G](\omega)P(d\omega)\text{ whenever }A\text{ is }G\text{-measurable}$$

Or equivalently:$$\mathbb E[\xi\mathbf1_A]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\xi\mid G]\mathbf1_A]\text{ whenever }A\text{ is }G\text{-measurable}$$

This can be expanded to the more general statement that: $$\mathbb E[\xi\psi]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\xi\mid G]\psi]\text{ whenever }\psi\text{ is }G\text{-measurable}$$

Now note that $\mathbb E[\eta\mid G]$ is by definition $G$-measurable so that we are allowed to conclude that:$$\mathbb E[\xi\mathbb E[\eta\mid G]]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\xi\mid G]\mathbb E[\eta\mid G]]\tag1$$

Similarly we have:$$\mathbb E[\eta\mathbb E[\xi\mid G]]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\eta\mid G]\mathbb E[\xi\mid G]]\tag2$$

Now note that $(1)$ and $(2)$ have equal RHS.

Comment: Thank you, i'll meditate on it

Comment: Can you explain me, why the integral and the next line are equivalente? I can't see it. And, how we can expange it to $\mathbb E[\xi \psi]$?

Comment: By definition $\int_AX(\omega)P(d\omega)=\int X(\omega) \mathbf1_A(\omega)P(d\omega)$ and $\mathbb E[X\mathbf1_A]$ is just another notation for the RHS. It can be expanded by first proving it for simple functions, then measurable functions that are limits of simple functions. It goes a bit too far to handle this in a comment. I reckon that you must have the disposal of some mathematical material that handles this stuff, don't you?

Comment: No, I don't. I will learn it later in university. I think, that second proof is more simple, than yours one, but yours is stronger.

Comment: Then where did you meet the question that you posed? Indeed the other answer (I upvoted it) is more direct. I tried to reveal something of the background of the equalities that you find there.

Comment: In the book, as an exercise, when I independently was engaged. Mathematics is hard for me at most, so I’m doing extra work myself.

Comment: But that book should also contain the mathematical stuff that is involved, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it was in theme, where wasn't definiton with integrals. I don't know why. I learned only definitions with sums for random discrete variables. About the second answer, can you explain me, why we can do second transition? It cause of we suggest, that it is independent?

Comment: Independence is not involved. Again it goes too far to give a college about it here in comments. Good luck with your  math study.  Also you can post your questions on this site of course.

Comment: Thank you. I'm understood, that it cause of conditional expectation is $G-$measurable :)

Answer (score 3):

From the law of total expectation

\begin{align*}
E\left(\xi E\left(\eta|G\right)\right) & =E\left(E\left(\xi E\left(\eta|G\right)|G\right)\right)\\
 & =E\left(E\left(\eta|G\right)E\left(\xi|G\right)\right)\\
 & =E\left(E\left(\eta E\left(\xi|G\right)|G\right)\right)\\
 & =E\left(\eta E\left(\xi|G\right)\right)
\end{align*}